# How to convert tensor of shape (36,) to (1,36)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am not familiar with numpy yet, I hope someone could help me.

The code is:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [1 , 36])
# L is a list from a list of lists.
sess.run(rnn_model , {x : L})
```

And the error is :

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (36,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, 36)'
```

I think this is because L is a list from a 2D list, python thinks that L must be a column list.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: use `tf.reshape` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape

Comment: Works, but I want to reshape the list, but not the tensor itself.

Comment: so, what is in `L`? can i see it's shape?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy` to reshape the `list L` and then use `tf.convert_to_tensor()`.

#### Example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(np.__version__)

L = [i for i in range(36)]
La = np.array(L).reshape((1,len(L))).astype(np.float32)
Lt = tf.convert_to_tensor(La)
print(y)
```

**Output**:

```
1.15.0
1.17.3
Tensor("Const_7:0", shape=(1, 36), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.expand_dims()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to convert list to column vector like this:

```
sess.run(rnn_model , {x : np.expand_dims(L, axis=0)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra dimension of size 1 with using fancy indexing by using None at desired position.

```
L[None, :]
```

Or

```
np.array(L)[None, :]
```

If L is not an ndarray.